# Image.FromStream get's stuck

Tags: c#, .net, networkstream

So my objective is to make a basic bare bones video streaming application.

For this purpose i am continuously capturing images through webcam and sending them through `NetworkStream` class (i know its a crude solution but as i said its just a basic bare bones app not for use in production environment).

So now the problem is in this line

```
Image img = Image.FromStream(receiveStream);
```

Now this blocks the thread its doesn't move on from this line. It is suppose to capture images from the stream so What is wrong here ?

Answer (score 3):

I suspect the problem is that the `NetworkStream` isn't closing, so `Image.FromStream` doesn't know when the current picture has completed.

Assuming you're in charge of the protocol, you could length-prefix each image, then when you're *reading* from the stream, you can read that exact number of bytes into a byte array, wrap that with a `MemoryStream`, and then pass that to `Image.FromStream`. That way each call to `Image.FromStream` gets a stream which ends after a single image.

So your `NetworkStream` would look like this:

```
Length (4 bytes)
Data for one image
Length (4 bytes)
Data for one image
// etc
```

Comment: Oh i didn't knew `Image.FromStream` requires `NetworkStream` to close for each picture. I am sending approximately 20 images per second through the stream and i just assumed that `Image.FromStream` would automatically find each image from stream. I'll now try to work around it thanks.

Comment: @WinCoder: It's only a suspicion - but it would make a certain amount of sense.

Answer (score 3):

You haven't gotten around to the *real* problem yet.  The Image.FromStream() method requires a stream whose CanSeek property is true.  The image decoder requires it.  This is however not the case for a NetworkStream, it cannot support seeking.

You *must* store the image in a MemoryStream first.  Once that's filled, set the Position back to 0 and call Image.FromStream().  Make sure you *don't* dispose or re-use the MemoryStream, that causes a very hard to diagnose GenericException later.  The image decoder is lazy and need to be able to access the stream when the image is rendered.

To make this work, you must know how much data to read from the NetworkStream.  In other words, you need to know how many bytes are present in a frame.  You can do so by having the transmitter first write an *int*, then the bytes in the image.  On the reading end you can then first read the 4 bytes from the stream and use BitConverter.ToInt32() to recover the length.  And can simply count-off the bytes in the stream to know when the MemoryStream is ready and Image.FromStream() can be called.

Once you've got that into place, you'll either have solved whatever bug is ailing your current code or have a very good way to debug it.